# python calculating intervals using foldleft using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, intervals, reduce

```
def tointervals(tlist):
      count=0
      for i in tlist:
        if count == 0:
          count = count + 1
          yield 0
        else:
          count = count + 1
          yield i - tlist[count -2]
```

I test it like so:

```
In [272]: list(tointervals([1,2,3,4,10]))
Out[272]: [0, 1, 1, 1, 6]
```

Great, that's exactly what I was looking for

But I want to do it in a more functional way (I'm mostly using Scala)

I'm terminally confused about this, mainly due to unfamiliarity with Python. The closest I've gotten before giving up in terminal confusion is this.

```
In [292]: reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0] + [y - x[0][x[1]] ],x[1]+1), [1,2,3,4,10], ([0],0))
Out[292]: ([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 8], 5)
```

Which is obviously wrong, but that's the direction I was trying... Am I being foolish, trying to use reduce, or can I just not code for toffee? Be gentle, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension will be more pythonic:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
>>> [y-x for x, y in zip(l, l[1:])]
[1, 1, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the Pythonic way, if I understand correctly what your intention is:

```
def tointervals(l):
    return [0] + [l[i] - l[i-1] for i in xrange(1, len(l))]
```

or

```
def tointervals(l):
    return (y-x for x,y in itertools.izip([l[0]] + l[:-1], l))
```

Functional programming is not considered a goal per se in the Python community and language support for it is limited -- ["practicality beats purity"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather go with one of more pythonic solutions from this thread, but if you want to see the `reduce`-based solution just for fun, it would be something like that:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0] + [y-x[1]], y), [1,2,3,4,10], ([], 0))
```

Please do not try that in real-life code because your colleagues will curse you.

Answer (score 0):

Building on larsmans' answer, you could also make a generator like you do in your procedural code:

```
def tointervals(xs):
    return itertools.chain((0,), (xs[i] - xs[i-1] for i in range(1, len(xs))))
```

Note: use `xrange` with python2.